# Javascript how do I document a variable that should be an Object of a specific type

Tags: javascript, parameters, webstorm, documentation

I am using WebStorm IDE.  I have several classes that have static functions.  For example the following will print "foo1_bar" to the console.

```
class Foo {
    static bar() {
        return "foo_bar";
    }
}

class Foo1 extends Foo {
    static bar() {
        return "foo1_bar";
    }
}

class Foo2 extends Foo {
    static bar() {
        return "foo2_bar";
    }
}

/**
 * @param {Object} type
 */
const test=(type)=>{
    console.log(type.bar());
}
test(Foo1);
```

This works and IDE says it is correct but I want to specify that the Object given to test must be of type Foo.  If I put Foo inside the {} though instead of Object it fails.  What is the proper way to document this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type name in `@param` annotation says that the parameter is an instance of corresponding type (i.e. created with `new type()`) so only the instance members are resolved.
You can try using `typeof` here:

```
class Foo {
    static bar() {
        return 'foo_bar'
    }
}

/**
 * @param {typeof Foo} type
 */
const test = type => {
    console.log(type.bar()) //Unresolved function or method bar()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of `type` using TypeScript:

For Example:

```js
'use strict';

class Foo {

    /**
     * Add property bar with no definite assignment assertion 
     * as bar is not defined in a constructor
     */ 
    bar!: typeof Foo.bar;

    static bar(): string {
        return "foo_bar";
    }
}

class Foo1 extends Foo {
    static bar(): string {
        return "foo1_bar";
    }
}

class Foo2 extends Foo {
    static bar(): string {
        return "foo2_bar";
    }
}

class Test {
    static bar(): string {
        return "foo_bar";
    }
}

class OneMore {
    static foo_bar(): string {
        return "foo_bar";
    }
}

/**
 * @param {Foo} type
 */
const test = (type: Foo): void => {
    console.log(type.bar());
}
test(Foo); // Works
test(Foo1); // Works
test(Foo2); // Works
test(Test); // Sadly works too..
test(OneMore); // Fails
```

Most of the code after remains as it is, with the exception of setting the return types and telling typescript about the type of your bar method.

There's one downside.. As you see the code `test(Test)` would compile correctly even if `Test` is not `typeof Foo`. This is because `Test` has the same structure as `Foo` and is statically compatible to `Foo`

[Pitfall: classes work structurally, not nominally](https://2ality.com/2020/02/types-for-classes-typescript.html#pitfall%3A-classes-work-structurally%2C-not-nominally)